# chevy 2010 colbalt

Tags: chevrolet

I have been having problems with my trunk popping open. Driving down the street sitting in the driveway.We changed the battery in my key because we thought it may be running low.  Now parked and in my driveway the lights are coming on, the locks are clicking. the lights go on for about three minutes the flashers flash, then it goes off and does it again. Anyone know anything about this> Help.